# Wordpress plugin addon

Tags: plugins

Hey I want to ask a question that maybe sounds stupid but I am new in wp plugin development.

I made a wp plugin that have to do with google maps. I have the basic version thats is free for anyone and i would like to offer especially for the members of my site the opportunity to download some additional features like change the color of the map etc.

So lets suppose that someone isn't a member of my site and download the basic version of the wp plugin and after decide to become a member for having access to the add-ons, how he will be able to load the add-on in wp dashboard without to download the whole plugin. I mean me as a developer how can i do this?

Something like a software that when you have an update you don't need to download the whole program but you download the update and load automatic in the existing program.

Thank you :)

Comment: I removed the wordpress.com tag, 3rd party plugins aren't allowed on WordPress.com, I expect you meant you have a self hosted site?

Comment: Yeap, i have a self hosted site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

### Additional Plugins

Similar to how Gravity forms works, you have the base plugin which is your standard plugin, then you build additional premium plugins that integrate into it using hooks to add additional functionality

### Enabling functionality

Your standard plugin bundles everything inside it, but disables sections of functionality until they're turned on. Turning them on may be via an API key for example

The payment aspects of each solution are going to be very specific to you and how your business model is going to work, so I won't/can't go in to that. Personally I would recommend the plugins route